# Change order of containers in mobile

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, w3.css

I am using **w3.css**, want to change order of containers when on mobile ( check screenshot below). Is there any class in w3.css which help changing order of blocks? I don't want to use standard css flex, just wanted to use **w3.css**

[image]

Comment: No, there is no flex properties in w3.css (and a simple word search would told you that)

Comment: If you post a code snippet there might be another rule that can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the *flexbox* tag I'm giving you the ***Flexbox*** solution:

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
}

.parent {
  display: flex; /* displays the children inline */
}

.child {
  flex: 1; /* children take as much horizontal space as they can */
  height: 100px;
}

.A {
  background: blue;
}

.B {
  background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) { /* adjust to your needs */
  .parent {
    flex-direction: column; /* stacks the children vertically */
  }
  .A {
    order: 2; /* changes the order, i.e. displays the .A below the .B */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child A">A</div>
  <div class="child B">B</div>
</div>
```

You can also do it with the ***Grid***:

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* could also use: 1fr 1fr or 50% 50% without the repeat() */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(100px, auto)); /* minimum height 100px, maximum height unlimited, adjust to your needs, you can also remove it, not mandatory */
}

.A {
  background: blue;
}

.B {
  background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .parent {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* could also use: 100% */
  }
  .A {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: careful with flex-direction column on mobile, iphone has some troubles with that when heights are dynamic.